# How to find r,theta using x,y coordinates in shell script

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote this code but didn't get the output

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1 $2
x=$1
y=$2
#echo "sum is $(($x+$y))"
#z=echo "r is $((($1*$1)+($2*$2)))"
#print z
z=$((($x*$x)+($y*$y)))
a=$((($y)/($x)))
echo "scale=5; sqrt($z)" | bc
b=`echo - | awk '{print (('$a' * 3.14159))}'`
k=`echo - | awk '{print (tan('$y'))}'`
echo $k
```

Comment: What does `echo -` do? Also, It seems you are not storing the result of `echo "scale=5; sqrt($z)" | bc`.

Comment: if you're going to use `awk` for some of the script then why not use `awk` for all of the script? you may also want to provide some sample inputs (int and real?) and expected outputs

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

bc -l <<< "x=$1; y=$2; sqrt(x*x + y*y); a(y/x)"
```

The first line of the output is *r* and the second line is *theta* in radians.

Comment: what is the `a()` function?

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин  Arctangent

Comment: can you suggest me  how to find tan inverse in shell script .

Comment: @TejasviTarone Shell has no support for floating-point arithmetic. You must use a utility such as `bc`. For example, in order to print the (approximate) value of  `arctan(1)` in radians, you can use this command: `bc -l <<< "a(1)"`

Comment: can you write a code to find theta